# iOS Charts does not show value labels when more than 3 data sets are plotted

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, ios-charts

I am using the charts framework for iOS in Objective-C.

I am trying to plot data value labels (y values) on a chart which has 4 data sets. if there are 1, 2 or 3 data sets on my chart, the label values show up just fine. If I add a 4th data set, the label values do not show up at all.

I am using a NSMutableArray of UIColor objects for each dataset. I set the label color to [UIColor clearColor] when I don't want the label to show up and I set it to [UIColor whiteColor] when I do want it to show up, for each data point.

```
NSMutableArray *labelColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *data in dataArray )
{
    if (condition)
    {
        [labelColors addObject:UIColor.whiteColor];
    }
    else
    {
        [labelColors addObject:UIColor.clearColor];
    }
}
    dataSet.valueColors = labelColors;
```

Again, this technique works fine if I plot 1, 2, or 3 data sets on my X axis, but if I plot a 4th data set, it stops drawing labels completely. The way I have my chart set up, two data sets are on the left Y axis and two data sets are on the right Y axis.

Does anybody know why my labels are not showing?

Comment: Hey Jackson please add some more details or screen shot of your issue so we can help you on this.

Comment: @CodeChanger I added more code showing how I set up my chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this with one line in viewDidLoad where I first set up my chart.

```
_chartView.maxVisibleCount = 500;
```

I guess after adding the 4th data set I had more than the default value of maxVisibleCount (whatever that is) and when that happens no data labels are drawn regardless of other settings.

I figured this out when modifying my data set's drawValuesEnabled field and inside the auto complete text it said "this value is ignored when maxVisibleCount is reached".